# Online sources for quantitative finance research

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, research, resource

What are the sources one can search for or view / download research articles and other publications on quantitative finance in addition to the Internet search engines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below are some of the sources one can use to search for and view or download research articles and other publications on quantitative finance (QF). Many include non-peer-reviewed articles in their search results. Most carry or index articles in languages other than English.

The list of sources for any category is not meant to be exhaustive. Sources are sorted semi-alphabetically within each category. For a wider list of sources that may or may not cover quantitative finance, see Wikipedia’s “[List of academic databases and search engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_databases_and_search_engines)”.

Only sources that can be accessed over the Internet are included. The curator or owner for each source, whenever available, as well as the requirement for a paid subscription are mentioned. Some of the sources may require a paid subscription for enhanced services even though their basic services are free. Most sources offer services, free or otherwise, in addition to those mentioned below.

#### Search and view or download:

**(multi-disciplinary)**

- [arXiv](https://arxiv.org): Articles in science, finance, engineering, and economics. Features a section on quantitative finance. (Community-curated, Cornell Univ. sponsored)
- [CORE](https://core.ac.uk): Open access research articles. (The Open University, non-profit)
- [Directory of Open Access Journals (DOAJ)](https://doaj.org): Open access articles only.  (Community-curated)
- [Internet Archive Scholar](https://scholar.archive.org): Research articles and other scholarly documents preserved in the Internet Archive. (The Internet Archive, non-profit)
- [Journal Storage (JSTOR)](https://www.jstor.org): Open access and paywalled articles and books. (Ithaca, non-profit).
- [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org): Open access articles only. Features a short summary created by artificial intelligence for each article. (Allen Institute for AI, non-profit)
- [Social Science Research Network (SSRN)](https://www.ssrn.com/): Preprint and early research articles platform. Obviously non-peer-reviewed. (Elsevier)
- [DeepDyve](https://www.deepdyve.com): Paid platform. Can search both paywalled and open access articles but can only view open access without subscription. (DeepDyve)
- [EBSCO Essentials](https://essentials.ebsco.com). Paid platform. Limited number of open access articles. Can search both paywalled and open access articles but can only view open access without subscription. (EBSCO Information Services)
- [J-Gate](https://jgateplus.com/): Paid platform for research articles. (Informatics India)
- [ScienceOpen](https://www.scienceopen.com): Search articles and download if open access. Allows post-publication review of articles. (ScienceOpen, non-profit)
- [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com): Paid platform. Limited number of open access articles. Can search both paywalled and open access articles but can only view open access without subscription. (Elsevier)
- [SpringerLink](https://link.springer.com): Paid platform to search and download articles from journals or books published by Springer. (Springer)
- [Taylor & Francis Online](https://www.tandfonline.com): Paid platform. Limited number of open access articles. Can search both paywalled and open access articles but can only view open access without subscription. (Information UK)
- [Wiley Online Library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com): Paid platform. Limited number of open access articles. Can search both paywalled and open access articles but can only view open access without subscription. (John Wiley & Sons)
- [Academia](https://www.academia.edu): Some articles may have copyright issues. (Academia.edu)
- [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net): Includes networking for researchers. Some articles may have copyright issues. (ResearchGate)

**(subject specialized)**

- [EconBiz](https://www.econbiz.de): Articles in economics and business studies. (Leibniz Information Centre for Economics, non-profit)
- [EconLit](https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/): Paid platform. Articles, books, and dissertations in economics. (American Economic Association, non-profit)
- [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/): Paid platform. Articles in mathematics and statistics. (American Mathematical Society, non-profit)
- [Quantpedia](https://quantpedia.com/): Paid platform dedicated to trading strategies based on various types of research. Provides access to the related articles. (ARIS Technologies)
- [Research Papers in Economics (RePEc)](http://repec.org): Articles in economics and related areas. (Sponsored by Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, non-profit)
- [Risk.net](https://www.risk.net): Paid platform. Website for the Risk magazine. Articles and news on risk management, derivatives, and regulation. (Infopro Digital Risk)
- [Wilmott](https://wilmott.com/): Paid platform. Website for the Wilmott magazine which is dedicated to quantitative finance. Access to all articles in the magazine only. (Wilmott Electronic Media)

#### Search and indexing:

- [Bielefeld Academic Search Engine (BASE)](https://www.base-search.net): Search for open access and paywalled articles. May provide external link to download an article if an open access version exists. (Bielefeld University, non-profit)
- [Crossref](https://www.crossref.org): Search for any article bearing a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) using keywords or DOI. (Publishers International Linking Association, trade organization)
- [Directory of Open Access Journals (DOAJ)](https://doaj.org): Search for open access articles with links to download.  (Community-curated, non-profit)
- [doi](https://www.doi.org/): Search for any article bearing a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) using its DOI. (International DOI Foundation)
- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com): Search for both open access and paywalled articles. May provide external link to download an article if an open access version exists. (Google)
- [MyScienceWork](https://www.mysciencework.com): Search for both open access and paywalled articles. (MyScienceWork)
- [Scopus](https://www.scopus.com): Paid platform. Wide-ranging abstract and citation database for peer-reviewed journals. (Elsevier)
- [Web of Science](https://access.clarivate.com/login?app=wos): Paid platform. Wide-ranging abstract and citation database for peer-reviewed journals. (Clarivate)

#### Connection discovery tools:

- [Connected Papers](https://www.connectedpapers.com): Free for occasional use. Visual tool to search for research articles. (Connected Papers)
- [Dimensions](https://app.dimensions.ai/): Paid platform with a free basic version. Shows the connections between articles as well as other research elements such as grants, patents, and datasets. (Digital Science & Research Solutions)
- [Inciteful](https://inciteful.xyz/): Visual tool to search for research articles. Also displays shortest path by articles between any two articles. (Community)
- [Litmaps](https://www.litmaps.com): Paid platform with a free basic version. Enhanced visual tool to search for articles. (Litmaps)
- [Scite_](https://scite.ai/): Paid platform with a free basic version. Helps find articles through evaluations that display the contexts of its citations. Allows uploading of an article PDF to check references. (Scite)

#### Doctoral dissertations and graduate theses:

- [DART-Europe E-Theses Portal](https://www.dart-europe.org/): Dissertations and theses from European universities.  (University of Central London, non-profit)
- [EBSCO Open Dissertations](https://biblioboard.com/opendissertations/): Dissertations from US universities. (EBSCO and BiblioLabs)
- [E-Theses Online Service (EThOS)](https://www.bl.uk/ethos-and-theses): Dissertations from UK universities. (British Library, non-profit)
- [Open Access Theses and Dissertations (OATD)](https://oatd.org): Dissertations and theses from universities around the world. (non-profit)
- [ProQuest](https://www.proquest.com): Dissertations, theses, and academic articles.  (Clarivate)
- [The Networked Digital Library of Theses and Dissertations (NDLTD)](https://ndltd.org): Dissertations and theses in English from US and other universities.  (NDLTD, non-profit)

#### Other tools:

- [EndNoteClick (Kopernio)](https://kopernio.com): Browser (Chrome) extension for finding PDF of any article. (Clarivate)
- [PaperPanda](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paperpanda-%E2%80%94-get-millions/ggjlkinaanncojaippgbndimlhcdlohf): Browser (Chrome) extension for finding PDF of any article. (—)
- [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com): Post-publication peer-review site. Allows users to discuss and review any article with a Digital Object Identifier (DOI). (The PubPeer Foundation, non-profit)
- [UnPayWall](https://unpaywall.org/): Browser (Chrome and Firefox) extension for downloading articles available free of charge wherever on the Internet. (OurResearch, non-profit)

#### Blogs:

- [QuantDare](https://quantdare.com): Short articles on finance vs artificial intelligence, asset management, risk management and finance vs programming. (ETS Asset Management Factory)
- [Quantocracy](https://quantocracy.com/): Links to selected articles from trading blogs that deal in the quantitative and the empirical. (—)
- [Turing Finance](http://www.turingfinance.com/): Archive of the blog by Stuart Reid on issues in QF. (Stuart Reid)

#### Books:

- [Google Books](https://books.google.com): Mainly for search. May or may not include samples from a book if found. (Google)