# First known reference using martingale theory to derive BS formula

Tags: black-scholes, reference-request, martingale

What is the first known paper which derives the Black-Scholes valuation formula for an option (1973) using martingale machinery - instead of PDEs?

Comment: I guess the  first formal treatment of the martingale approach might be [Harrison and Kreps (1979)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022053179900437). [Cox and Ross (1976)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304405X76900234) also have very early work on risk-neutral pricing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Online sources for quantitative finance research](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73853/online-sources-for-quantitative-finance-research)

Comment: See a modern martingale based derivation https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2631772