# Reference Request Adjusting implied/historical volatility for earnings

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, earnings

Wanted a reference request for any source has discussed how to clean/adjust historical volatility/ historical implied volatility time series for Earnings. The RV/IV time series data have a lot of outliers around earnings which can be detrimental to model data for normal regimes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Online sources for quantitative finance research](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73853/online-sources-for-quantitative-finance-research)

Comment: Was looking for a specific advise. Cannot find it myself.