# Value: High-minus-low factor fama french - transaction costs

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, fama-french, transaction-costs

Anyone know any references on how to estimate transaction costs for a give trading strategy?
In more specific terms, if I want to estimate the returns on an HML value strategy as in Fama-French 1993, how would I go about it?

Comment: You know the papers by [Novy-Marx and Velikov (2016, RFS)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/29/1/104/1844518) and [Patton and Weller (2020, JFE)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X20300453)?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just came across those. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Online sources for quantitative finance research](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73853/online-sources-for-quantitative-finance-research)

Comment: @Alper, no not at all.